# Spring cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'channel'

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

I have below contexto.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
  xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
  xmlns:int="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd"
  default-init-method="iniciar" 
  default-destroy-method="destruir">

    <import resource="otherfile.xml"/>
    <import resource="otherfile2.xml"/>


<!-- other stuff -->

<!-- A Spring Integration channel -->
<int:channel id="helloWorldChannel" />

<!-- A Spring Integration adapter that routes messages sent to the helloWorldChannel to the bean named "helloServiceImpl"'s hello() method -->
<int:service-activator input-channel="helloWorldChannel" ref="helloServiceImpl" method="hello" />
```

When editing this file in eclipse, it marks 'channel' as error. Editor says below message:

```
cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'channel'. One of '{"http://
 www.springframework.org/schema/beans":import, "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans":alias, 
 "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans":bean, WC[##other:"http://www.springframework.org/
 schema/beans"], "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans":beans}' is expected.
```

Anyway I can build the application and execute but in run time below exception is generated:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException: Line 47 in XML document from class path resource [contexto.xml] is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 47; columnNumber: 39; cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Se ha encontrado contenido no válido a partir del elemento 'channel'. Se esperaba uno de '{"http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans":import, "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans":alias, "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans":bean, WC[##other:"http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"], "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans":beans}'.
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:399)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:336)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:304)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:181)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:217)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:188)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:252)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractXmlApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractXmlApplicationContext.java:127)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractXmlApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractXmlApplicationContext.java:93)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:129)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:609)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:510)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
    at com.distributed.analyzer.Main.main(Main.java:33)
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 47; columnNumber: 39; cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Se ha encontrado contenido no válido a partir del elemento 'channel'. Se esperaba uno de '{"http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans":import, "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans":alias, "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans":bean, WC[##other:"http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"], "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans":beans}'.
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.error(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator$XSIErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.reportSchemaError(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.handleStartElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.emptyElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.DOMParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultDocumentLoader.loadDocument(DefaultDocumentLoader.java:76)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadDocument(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:429)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:391)
    ... 14 more
```

If then I replace the below start line in contexto.xml file:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
```

by

```
<beans:beans xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
```

then 'channel' is recognized and editor no longer marks it as error but import line is marked as error now:

```
cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'import'. One of '{"http://
 www.springframework.org/schema/beans":description, "http://www.springframework.org/schema/
 beans":import, "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans":alias, "http://www.springframework.org/
 schema/beans":bean, WC[##other:"http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"], "http://
 www.springframework.org/schema/beans":beans}' is expected.
```

*UPDATED*

I have added int namespace before chanel but it continues saying there is an error. Anyway I can build and execute the app but below exception is thrown:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: Unable to locate Spring NamespaceHandler for XML schema namespace [http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration]
Offending resource: class path resource [contexto.xml]

    at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.FailFastProblemReporter.error(FailFastProblemReporter.java:70)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.ReaderContext.error(ReaderContext.java:85)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.ReaderContext.error(ReaderContext.java:80)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.error(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:301)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1408)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1401)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.parseBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:168)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.doRegisterBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:138)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.registerBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:94)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.registerBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:508)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:392)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:336)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:304)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:181)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:217)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:188)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:252)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractXmlApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractXmlApplicationContext.java:127)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractXmlApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractXmlApplicationContext.java:93)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:129)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:609)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:510)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
    at com.distributed.analyzer.Main.main(Main.java:33)
```

Finally I have added below lines to xsi:schemaLocation:

```
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/spring-integration.xsd
```

After adding above two lines, no errors are marked within context.xml but when I execute the app, another exception is thrown:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: Unable to locate Spring NamespaceHandler for XML schema namespace [http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration]
Offending resource: class path resource [contexto.xml]

    at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.FailFastProblemReporter.error(FailFastProblemReporter.java:70)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.ReaderContext.error(ReaderContext.java:85)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.ReaderContext.error(ReaderContext.java:80)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.error(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:301)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1408)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1401)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.parseBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:168)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.doRegisterBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:138)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.registerBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:94)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.registerBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:508)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:392)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:336)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:304)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:181)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:217)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:188)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:252)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractXmlApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractXmlApplicationContext.java:127)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractXmlApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractXmlApplicationContext.java:93)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:129)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:609)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:510)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
    at com.distributed.analyzer.Main.main(Main.java:33)
```

Also I have tried to specify a version in contexto.xml:

```
http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/spring-integration.xsd
```

that is:

```
http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/spring-integration-1.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/spring-integration-2.0.xsd
```

but it is not working, same exception is thrown in run time.

***LAST UPDATE***

Some dependencies were missed in maven pom.xml file. I have added below dependencies:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-integration-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-integration-jms</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```

Now it works! ;)

Answer (score 2):

You have to use the defined namespace for the resource you are using, on your case:

```
<int:channel id="helloWorldChannel" />
```

Comment: You are right. int namespace was missing. I have added it but chanel continues marked as error in context.xml so I have added two lines *.xsd for spring integration, and now another exception is shown. See my updated post please. thx

Comment: What is the `contexto.xml` file that the exception is complaing of? There is no mention of it on your question. Is it your context file?

Comment: Yes, sorry, contexto.xml is context.xml. I  did a mistake when posting it, I have corrected it in the post.

Comment: I'm not seeing any more problems with your XML it is right with all updates and it also is following the [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/configuration.html) Maybe it is a refreshing issue. Sometimes the IDE does not update your application right. Try to run a project clean and also clean your container to see what happens.

Comment: Finally I have solved it. Some dependencies were missed in maven pom.xml file. See my last update. thx.

Comment: That's great to hear! :)